# "match-not-found" on products url rewrite

Tags: magento

I'm trying to fix a few product's URLs and I've been doing the following process:

1. I run this on the database:  `delete from core_url_rewrite;`
2. On the CMS I go to `system > index management > GATALOG URL REWRITES` and ask to rewrite it;

And then when I go on the CMS to `Catalog > Url Rewrite Management` and search for the `products`, on the column `Request Path` I get a lot of `match-not-found-XXX` , where `XXX` are different numbers.

It is happening with many products and I've done and redone the process above and still getting the same resuls.

I can't figure why it is happening. Any clue?

Answer (score 0):

Magento usually adds the number 'XXX' to the url-path if another product already has the same path. Is there any chance that you imported those products and something gone wrong there?

Check the urk_key values for all those products and see what they are set too.

That's about the best clue I have right now, good luck!

Comment: hey butterbrot. yes, I know about the sequence XXX on magento. My point on the question is: why the rewrite is creating name-keys with match-not-found?

Comment: right, but I was wondering if its not the url rewrie that is creating that url but something else, so that's why I am wondering what the actual attribute values are for url_key, are those correct what they are supposed to be or do they already contain the "match-not-found" bit